# Does CRAN require separate files for each .R and .cpp function in packages?

Tags: c++, r, package, cran

I want to submit an R package to CRAN. All packages that I know have a separate .R or .cpp file for each of their .R or .cpp functions, respectively. Is this a necessary property for a package to be accepted by CRAN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You *could* have all your R code in one file `R/myfile.R` and all your C++ code in `src/myfile.cpp`.  But files are "transient" anyway in the sense that R now bytecompiles all R code into another internal representation, and of course always compiled native source code in C, C++, Fortran, ... as needed into object code that is loaded dynamically as needed.

You have to pass `R CMD check --as-cran` and adhere to the CRAN Repo Policy otherwise but there is no restriction that each function needs a source file -- entirely up to you to organise as you see fit.